# Как указать тип "Color?" в XAML WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Народ, мне нужно в `TargetType` указать класс не `Color`, а `Color?`. Т.е. цвет, который может иметь значение `Null`. Указать `TargetType="Color"` я могу, а вот указать `TargetType="Color?"` - я не могу. Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: Оригинальная формулировка вопроса =)

Comment: XAML
You cannot declare this managed class in XAML, but you can use its static properties to assign values in XAML.

Answer (score 4):

Посмотрите, что вернёт `typeof(Color?).ToString()`.

Вообще говоря, `Color?` - это `System.Nullable<System.Drawing.Color>`. Посмотрите в сторону, как в xaml представлять generic-типы.